# Parse HTML with Mechnize/Ruby and go to next element if not existing

Tags: ruby, parsing, mechanize

I like to build a scraper using mechanize gem. a few things work just fine but I face a problem when the structure of the html I like to parse changes e.g. doesn't contain all requested elements.

here is what I did so far and this works just fine:

```
require 'mechanize'

mechanize = Mechanize.new

################ GET TOTAL NUMBER OF PAGES ################
page = mechanize.get("https://yellow.local.ch/de/q?browse=physiotherapy&where=&page=1")
total_pages = page.search(".page").last.at("a").text.strip.to_i

########## LOOP OVER EACH PAGE ##############

total_pages.times do |page_num|
  puts ("https://yellow.local.ch/de/q?browse=physiotherapy&where=&page=#{page_num + 1}")
  page = mechanize.get("https://yellow.local.ch/de/q?browse=physiotherapy&where=&page=#{ page_num + 1}")
  containers = page.search(".container")

  # ################ GET DATA FOR EACH PAGE ####################
  containers.each do |container|
    firma = container.at("h2").text.strip
    categories = container.search(".categories").at("span").text.strip
    address = container.search(".address").at("span").text.strip
    phone = container.search(".contact").at("a").text.strip


############## URL empty ######################


  end
```

this is the HTML I like to parse

```
 <div class="container clearfix">
<h2>
<a class="details-entry-title-link" href="https://yellow.local.ch/de/d/Arlesheim/4144/Physiotherapie/panta-rhei-KfNsAr3NLV8NSL4Z1Q3CQA">panta rhei</a>
</h2>
<div class="listing-index-content">
<span class="categories first-two">Physiotherapie</span>
<br>
<span class="address first-two">Tramweg 2, 4144 Arlesheim</span>
<br>
<span class="contact last-two">
<span class="phone">
<label>Telefon</label>
<span class="value"><span class="star">*</span><a rel="nofollow" class="number" href="tel:+41617016318">061 701 63 18</a>
</span>
</span>

|
<span class="url">
<a class="redirect" data-href="https://www.local.ch/redirect?entity_id=KfNsAr3NLV8NSL4Z1Q3CQA&amp;hmac=926efdfbc1e4c457a45e16b4e903b8dfdff31c8f&amp;locale=de&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pantarhei-arlesheim.ch" href="http://www.pantarhei-arlesheim.ch">www.pantarhei-arlesheim.ch</a>
</span>

</span>
<br>
<span class="icons last-two">
<span id="heart-place_KfNsAr3NLV8NSL4Z1Q3CQA">
<button class="button-reseted heart" data-action="favorited" data-create="/de/favorites?place_id=KfNsAr3NLV8NSL4Z1Q3CQA" data-delete="/de/favorites/:id">
<i class="heart-icon icon-heart-outline"></i>
</button>
<span class="interestingness" data-load-with="<span class=&quot;bootstrap&quot;><i class=&quot;icon-spinner icon-spin&quot;></i></span>">
2
</span>
</span>

</span>
<a class="big info-link button details-entry-link-button" href="https://yellow.local.ch/de/d/Arlesheim/4144/Physiotherapie/panta-rhei-KfNsAr3NLV8NSL4Z1Q3CQA" title="panta rhei">Details</a>
</div>
</div>
```

sometimes the part ** span class="url" ** does not exist. therefore I guess I have to check the container if there is such an element. If yes all good if not skip it and to go next element to parse.

thanks for helping.

Comment: Not sure if copy/paste issue but it looks like you are missing an `end`.

Comment: You can use `next` to skip an iteration of a loop, e.g. `next if some_condition`

Comment: how would that next look like?

Comment: e.g. `next`,  `next if some_condition`, `next if true`, `next if false`

Comment: .any helped me.

if container.search(".contact").css(".url").any?
        url = container.search(".url").at("a").text
        else
        url = "no website"
      end